# RIMO III (elevation: 7,233 m, coordinates, 35°22′31″N 77°21′42″E): first ascent date?

Tags: history, india, himalaya

**RIMO III** is one the 6 peaks of the Rimo mountain massif, situated in Indian Kashmir.

**First ascent**: 1985, by an Indian/ British expedition led by Harish Kapadia.

Can't find the exact date of this event (day/month/year).

Anyone out there has this information? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Himalayan Journal, it was July 14th, 1985.

> 1. Rimo III
>
> (7233 m -23,730 ft)
>
> Wilkinson and Fotheringham  14 July
>
> NE ridge
>   From east via
>   South Rimo
>   glacier.

[EXPLORING 'THAT VALLEY'-TERONG](https://www.himalayanclub.org/hj/42/13/exploring-that-valley-terong/)  
by HARISH KAPADIA